# Connect Bot Framework Emulator to dockerized bot

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer, botframeworkemulator

I've trouble to understand the process to connect the Bot Framework Emulator to a bot, that runs within a local Docker container.

I created a (NodeJS) bot with the help of the Bot Framework Composer. I can start the bot with the IDE and connect to it via the Bot Framework Emulator successfully:

1. [Start chatbot via Bot Framework Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bnjn.png)
2. [Verify chatbot connect in Bot Framework Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjkTa.png)

Next, I put the application into a Docker Container, exposed the port 3978 and started it locally again. I can successfully verify, that the container is running

3. [Verify running Docker Container on CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7kiu.png)

I can additionally verify, that the bot application is running in the container and that is accessible by calling the endpoint **localhost:3978/api/messages** in my browser.

For me it seems, that the bot is running in the Docker container, because there is a statement, that a route does not exist (understandable, because GET api/messages is not implemented)

4. [Verify if bot is running within the Docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AKd4.png)

I then created a new endpoint configuration in Bot Framework Emulator to connect to my locally deployed bot in the Docker container:

5. [Add endpoint configuration to dockerized chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD9wd.png)

Now the issue appears: If I open the endpoint connection, I receive a 500 error (connection refused).

6. [Verify Bot Framework emulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xj0U.png)

Does someone have an idea, what's actually going on here?

What's the difference between:

- starting the bot with "npm run dev" (= bot is available at http://localhost:3978/api/messages) and
- starting the bot with a Docker container (= bot is available at http://localhost:3978/api/messages)

I found following issue on GitHub, but this didn't help:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/356

It seems that the user here was one step further than me, because my setup already fails during connection time and in the GitHub issue the user had issues "sending" messages to a already connected bot.

Thanks in advance for any guidance here!

Comment: So, you've containerized the bot, but are unable to connect to it outside the container, correct? The obvious solution might be to check your container networking settings to ensure that the port the bot is on (it might not be 3978 if something else has claimed it) is accessible from outside the container. It wouldn't be by default.

Comment: Hi @AP01, 
I think I can connect to the containerized bot application from the outside (= from my local env), because on step 4, I receive an answer from the application.

I assume the problem is the other direction, so that the bot can not send an answer back to the emulator.

My current approach to solve my (still existing) issue is 
1) to deploy the containerized bot on my AKS cluster
2) create an Azure Bot Service resource
3) configure the bot identity of the composer project to connect to the Azure Bot Service resource and
4) try to connect the Emulator via DirectLine

Comment: Are you able to setup a tunneling solution (such as ngrok) within the container, and set that as your Azure messaging endpoint? Emulator is not very good at handling weird remote connections.

Comment: Maybe, but I think this should also work without ngrok when I deploy the containerized bot application to my AKS cluster and connect the Azure Bot Service endpoint to the container. Actually I was able to do that with a containerized bot that was developed with the Bot Framework SDK (= I was able to chat with the bot after the AKS deployment). But I have still trouble to do the same with containerized Bot Framework Composer applications - so it seems not to be a problem with the Emulator after all, but with the setup of the Framework Composer application.

Comment: Composer is special and is designed to work in a very specific way. Complex applications such as containerization should not be done with Composer. You should probably stick to using SDK bots, as you've already gotten working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @AP01 - this was also my impression :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I had the same problem. Here is how I fixed it if that can help someone:

In your `docker-compose.yml` config, you need to expose the port running your bot inside your container to your localhost, so that the Bot Framework Emulator can talk to it

```
ports:
      - "3978:3978"
```

Then you also need to let your bot see what's running on localhost, to respond to the Bot Framework Emulator. The following line lets you connect to things running on your `http(s)://localhosthost:(port)` by calling `http(s)://host.docker.internal:(port)` from within your container. [See documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts)

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Finally, in your Bot Framework Emulator settings:

- Tick `Bypass ngrok for local addresses`
- Set localhost override to `host.docker.internal`
- Save

You should then be able to connect to `Open Bot`

- Bot URL: `http://localhost:3978/api/messages`
- Leave everything else blank
- Connect

Answer (score 0):

What help me.

**Docker Compose settings**

ports:

- '3334:80'

extra_hosts:

- "localhost:host-gateway"

For test I use Bot Framework Emulator